# How to display callbacks in sequence diagrams Visio 2013?

Tags: callback, visio, sequence-diagram

I want to sketch a sequence diagram including callbacks. Poorly Visio 2013 transforms my arrows / messages in dashed return messages. How can I disable this behavior?

Here is a minimal example. All Messages are inserted as Messages, two of them were transformed to return messages, but only one correctly. Selecting the wrong arrow and change it to non-dashed line style has no effect.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=86263C7E45616D34!53626&authkey=!AA2V01jvNCiZ3TM

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671542/uml-class-modeling-of-callback-functions-classes

Comment: Thanks for response, but I have no problem with implementation. In fact I have a problem using the visualization tool.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps you should ask your question on superuser.com too - you might have a better response.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. It is possible to rotate the connector element on Z-axis about 180°. This destroys the vector behavior on PDF export and has still the wrong semantic, but seems to be a cosmetic solution.